# Laravel Query Builder SUM with where clause

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-query-builder

I have the following relationship: *Items has many Records (Records.item_id references Items.id)*.

I have this query working fine:

```
$items = Item::addSelect(['quantity_sum' => Record::selectRaw('sum(quantity) as total')
                                ->whereColumn('item_id', 'items.id')
                                ->groupBy('item_id')
                             ])
                    ->get();
```

But I need to get just the Items where the sum of records.quantity is lower than 1. I have tried add *->where('quantity_sum', '1')* but I get this error message:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'quantity_sum' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `items`.*, (select sum(quantity) as total from `records` where `item_id` = `items`.`id` group by `item_id`) as `quantity_sum` from `items` where `quantity_sum` = 1)

Why can't I use the quantity_sum alias?
How can I filter only the Items whose sum in the Records.quantity column is less than 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **HAVING**

Something like that:

```
->havingRaw('sum(quantity) > ?', [1])
```

Edit:

```
$items = Item::addSelect(['quantity_sum' => Record::selectRaw('sum(quantity) as total')->whereColumn('item_id', 'items.id')->groupBy('item_id')])
    ->havingRaw('quantity_sum < ?', [1])
    ->groupBy('items.id') 
    ->get();
```

Comment: This tip was good! I got it by this way: 
->havingRaw('quantity_sum < ?', [1])
->groupBy('items.id')

Comment: May you edit your answer to correspond the final code?

$items = Item::addSelect(['quantity_sum' => Record::selectRaw('sum(quantity) as total')
                                          ->whereColumn('item_id', 'items.id')
                                          ->groupBy('item_id')
                                         ])
       ->havingRaw('quantity_sum < ?', [1])
       ->groupBy('items.id')
                     ->get();

Answer (score 1):

you should define the relation between Item and Record Models like this:

in Item Model :

```
public function records()
{
return $this->hasMany(Record::class,'item_id');
}
```

in Record Model:

```
public function item()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Item::class,'item_id');
}
```

and simply in your query use 'doesntHave' like this:

```
$itemsWithoutRecords= Item::doesntHave('records')->get();
```

and if you like 'count' way  you could use 'withCount' like:

```
$itemsWithoutRecords= Item::withCount('records')->having('records_count','<',1)-> get();
```

notice: both ways needs correct relation between the models

first way: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

second way: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: The relationship is built right. The count is not the point here. I want to filter according to the sum of a column of a nested table. 
First sum(records.quantity) as quantity_sum and than bring just the quantity_sum < 0.

Comment: why getting all result from db and then filtering, didn't you should filter in query?
if you want this you could use:
$items= Item::withCount('records')-> get()->where('records_count','<',$theNumberYouWant);